# Sleep() inline assembly call works but generates runtime check-failure

Tags: c, assembly, stack, sleep, inline-assembly

As the title of my question says the sleep() function works properly (and every other function call in the C function, the problem is that after it's finished running I get an error that says:

"Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention."

I believe the way I'm handling the registers when I call the sleep function is done properly because it actually works, I posted the whole function just in case it's needed to detect where I might be misplacing the stack contents in another function call.

The function basically prints an elevator going up from the last floor on the bottom to the top-most one.

```
 int deSubidaASM() {

int  sleepTime = 900;          
char *clear = "cls";
char *piso = "[x]";
char *pisoVacio = "[ ]";
char *texto = "%s\n";
char *fuerza = "Fuerza G: 1";


_asm {

        mov ebx, 0             //int a=0
        mov ecx, 9             //int b=9

        _while1:               //while (a <= 9)
        cmp ebx, 9             //
        jg _fin               //if ebx>9, end

        _Fuerza:          //writes on screen
        mov eax, fuerza
        push eax
        mov eax, texto
        push eax
        mov esi, ecx   //
        call printf
        mov ecx, esi   //
        pop edx
        pop edx     

        _sleep:
        mov eax, sleepTime
        push eax               //pushes the sleep time input
        mov esi, ebx         //auxiliary variable to keep the cycle counters
        mov edi, ecx           //same as the above line comment
        call Sleep             //sleep()  call
        mov ecx, edi           //returns the values from the aux variables
        mov ebx, esi           //same as the above line comment
        pop eax                //cleans the stack


        _clearscreen:
         mov eax, clear         //Bloque para clearscreen
         push eax
         mov esi, ebx
         mov edi, ecx
         call system
         mov ecx, edi
         mov ebx, esi
         pop edx


        _while2 :                //while (b >= 0) 
        cmp ecx, 0              //
        jle _resetearWhile2     //if ecx<0 restart while2       


        cmp ebx, ecx             // if the levels match 
        je _printPiso           //print elevator
        jne _printVacio         //print floor


        _printPiso :
        mov eax, piso
        push eax
        mov eax, texto
        push eax
        mov esi, ecx   //
        call printf
        mov ecx, esi   //
        pop edx
        pop edx
        dec ecx
        jmp _while2

        _printVacio :
        mov eax, pisoVacio
        push eax
        mov eax, texto
        push eax
        mov esi, ecx       //
        call printf
        mov ecx, esi       //
        pop edx
        pop edx
        dec ecx
        jmp _while2


        _resetearWhile2:
        mov ecx, 9              //b=9
        inc ebx            
        jmp _while1            


        _fin :

}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you just push and pop the registers you want preserving (and ESP as the error message advises) instead of trying to juggle between other registers?

Comment: @WeatherVane : Do you mean I should push what's on the ESP register into another before the function call and then return it after the function call to preserve it's contents? I tried that and I get another error "Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WinApi [Sleep()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx) function follows the [STDCALL calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall).  It had already cleaned up the stack when it returns. When you do the same, the stack is "overcleaned" ;-). Remove the line:

```
    pop eax                //cleans the stack
```

I don't know what compiler you use. My compiler (Visual Studio 2010) needs another call to [Sleep()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx):

```
call dword ptr [Sleep]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right, it works now!. In VS2015 calling sleep using 

  ` call Sleep `

works just fine, I was using the call method you use before another member in here pointed it out.

Answer (score 0):

Too much for a comment. I mean push and pop the registers you are interested in preserving, including those you are juggling around from `esi <-> ebx` and `edi <-> ecx`.

```
_sleep:
push    ecx                 // save the regs
push    edx
push    ebp

mov     eax, sleepTime      // func argument
push    eax                 // pushes the sleep time input
call    Sleep               // sleep() call
pop     eax                 // clean off stack

pop     ebp                 // restore regs
pop     edx
pop     ecx
```

Comment: Tried this (pushing the ecx and edx registers which are the ones I'm interested in preserving), didn't work, still getting the same error.

Comment: Why didn't you push `ebp`? And yes, sorry I got the other regs the wrong way round. Corrected.

Comment: I had also pushed ebp sorry I didn't specify that, but still it wouldn't work.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help, but generally, please push/pop registers you want to preserve instead of shuffling them to other registers.

Comment: But I was going to suggest removing the `pop eax` from after the `sleep()` call, since the error was about stack misalignment from different calling conventions. In some conventions, the arguments are removed from the stack by the function itself. I don't see why `sleep` would be different, but if you are sure this function caused the error, you could try.

Comment: Oh - sorry an answer beat me. I should have said earlier ;)